# How to stop a thread running on a service from any activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, handler

I have a service that runs on the main UI thread from where I start a new thread which repeats a method for every 30 seconds. I have been trying to stop the thread from other activities on the onpause() method ( when the device goes to sleep) but that doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong? Anyone can help?

My Repeating Task Thread

```
HandlerThread hThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
    hThread.start();

    final Handler handler = new Handler(hThread.getLooper());
    final long oneMinuteMs = 30 * 1000;

     Runnable eachMinute = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmIntentService.class);
            startService(service);
            handler.postDelayed(this, oneMinuteMs);

        }
    };// Schedule the first execution
    handler.postDelayed(eachMinute, oneMinuteMs);
```

as seen [here](http://binarybuffer.com/2012/07/executing-scheduled-periodic-tasks-in-android)

Comment: You need to provide the code for what you are doing in `onPause()`.  In general, you need to treat your `Service` and `Activity` as separate components of your app and not directly touch one from the other.  Use `Intent`s or a bound service for the interaction.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer thank you for your answer but I am afraid I don't understand what you are saying. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Are you using an Android `Service` for this, or are you calling you `Runnable` you are posting to the background thread your "service"?

Comment: @LarrySchiefer From my Service that runs on the main UI thread I create a new thread that calls an other intentservice. The runnable method creates a new thread, different from the one that the Service runs to

Comment: If you're using a `Service` derived class to start an `IntentService` derived class, you're most likely making this far more complex than needed.  All `Service` components run their main entry points (`onStartCommand()`, `onCreate()`, etc.) on the main thread.  The exception is `onBind()`.  The `IntentService` automatically spawns a temporary thread to handle the incoming `Intent`, then exits when no more `Intent's are left to be processed.

Comment: I understand your point but everything is like I need them to be. For example, I am using the runnable and handler that creates a new thread and calls an intentservice only for the option of getting called again every x sec(in this case its 30 sec). About my problem on how to stop the thread, how can I achieve that?

Comment: You don't need a `Service` for any of that.  You can use your `HandlerThread` from within your `Activity`.  Don't keep creating new `Runnable` objects.  Create a single one and track it as a member field of your `Activity` or other controller component.  When `onPause()` is executed, just call `handler.removeCallbacks(theRunnable)`.  You only need to use a `Service` if you have _long running background tasks_ which are not dependent on the UI being present.

Comment: I am using my main Service for receiving location callbacks and uploading points to a server, that is why I need service. Now I am using a new thread that calls intent service to upload more points based on a timer(30s). I might be wrong though but I believe that is how things should be. If not I will be happy to have a chat about it and navigate me through :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to stop that, you need to send a stop message on the Handler (and you don't really need more complex operations and classes)
To do so, implement create a method that actually determine if your handler should stop or not, when it receives another message.

For example, implementing a Singlethon class named `AlarmManager` that handles the repeating tasks

```
public class AlarmManager implements Handler.Callback {

private static final String TAG = AlarmManager.class.getName();

/**
 * The message "what" sent to the handler in order to stop
 */
private final int STOP_MESSAGE_ID = 0;

private static AlarmManager sInstance;

private Handler mHandler;

private Runnable mExecutionRunnable;

/**
 * Generates a single instance of this class
 */
public static AlarmManager getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new AlarmManager();
    }
    return sInstance;
}

/**
 * Private constructor to avoid initializing this class by constructor.
 * {@link #getInstance()} should be used instead in order to assure that only one
 * instance of this class exists
 */
private AlarmManager() {
    mHandler = new Handler(this);
}

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
    switch (message.what) {
        case STOP_MESSAGE_ID:
            //Remove all stop messages
            mHandler.removeMessages(STOP_MESSAGE_ID);
            //Remove all callbacks
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mExecutionRunnable);
            Log.d(TAG, "Stopping Operations");
            break;
        default:
            mHandler.handleMessage(message);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}

    /**
     * Schedule operations to start after a delay, and the operation will repeat after a period of time specified
     *
     * @param beforeStartDelay Delay in milliseconds before the first start
     * @param repeatTimeDelay Repeat delay in milliseconds between executions
     */
    public void scheduleExecutions(final long beforeStartDelay, final long repeatTimeDelay) {
    mExecutionRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
//                Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),     AlarmIntentService.class);
//                startService(service);
            Log.d(TAG, "Executing operation again");
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, repeatTimeDelay);
        }

    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mExecutionRunnable,beforeStartDelay);

}

/**
 * Cancels the repeating executions
 */
public void stopExecution() {
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(STOP_MESSAGE_ID);
}
```

}

As you can see, this handles the repeating steps with delay, and prints a Log message on each execution (currently set by method parameter), and also prints a Log when it stops.

In order to control this flow, just hook it up with your `Activity` lifecycle for example.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    AlarmManager.getInstance().stopExecution();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AlarmManager.getInstance().scheduleExecutions(0,3000);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me more information about it, like where to place that method? In my service and access it through an instance of the service class? Also, using .quit() and .interrupt() isn't it a non recommended way?

Comment: Your code above is contained into some kind of class and because this method accesses both `hThread` and handler, it should go to the same class in order for it to be able to access those fields.

Comment: So that method goes to my Service class and I just access it through an instance of the Service class?

Comment: @AnninosKyriakou you can do that, or you can wrap this functionality into a different class, for example AlarmManager (that can be implemented as Singleton) that exposes some methods used to control the flow (stopAlarms(), startAlarms(), etc), and the code above goes there, into AlarmManager

Comment: Alarm Manager won't work since it does not accept repeating tasks in periods less than one minute. Android Developers page suggested to use a handler for less than one minute.

Comment: @AnninosKyriakou I was saying about a different class, created by you that is named AlarmManager, not about the platform specific AlarmManager

Comment: Oh okay, my bad. Still not sure though how to do it but I will give it a try. Thank you :)

Comment: @AnninosKyriakou  I've edited my answer with an actually implementation and javadoc to explain what i was saying previously. Hope that this will make some light on how to handle your situation. Keep an eye on the logs in order to track the execution.

Comment: Thank you very much for it. Some things I realised, this runs on the main UI thread rather on a new thread and the repeating task happens every 3 sec rather than every 30 sec. I believe that now I understand what I was doing wrong and I will be able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best approach, but why don't you do a check?

For example:

```
public class Generic {
private boolean isLooping = true;

...
    HandlerThread hThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
    hThread.start();

    final Handler handler = new Handler(hThread.getLooper());
    final long oneMinuteMs = 30 * 1000;

    Runnable eachMinute = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(isLooping) {
                Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmIntentService.class);
                startService(service);
                handler.postDelayed(this, oneMinuteMs);
            }

        }
    };// Schedule the first execution
    handler.postDelayed(eachMinute, oneMinuteMs);

...

public void setLooping(boolean isLooping) {
    this.isLooping = isLooping;
}
```

Comment: I have tested it and it doesn't work. Unless I am doing something wrong. I am accessing the setLooping() method through an instance of the service.